# Элемент, который не будет выходить за приделы родитеского элемента

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка:

```
<Button x:Name="InstallSomethingButton" Width="{Binding ... /*200*/}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,1,0">
    <Grid Width="200" Height="{Binding ElementName=InstallSomethingButton, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Label x:Name="InstallSomethingModpackTitle" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-2,0,0"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="InstallSomethingSubTitle" Margin="0,16,0,0" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
        <ProgressBar Background="#FF3C3C3C" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Value="100" Padding="0"></ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

P.S. `<Grid Width = "200"...` сделано для того, что бы растянуть ProgressBar на всю ширину кнопки.

Выглядит это все вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ProgressBar более светлый, кнопка - более темная. Как заставить ProgressBar не выходить за пределы кнопки (по краям)?

Comment: Установите кнопке `ClipToBounds`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не работает. Установил - ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Приведите полный пример компоновки (желательно не усложняя стилями и прочими вещами не относящимися к вопросу), потому что изначально контент в кнопке выравнивается по центру, а не растягивается и ничего не обрезается.

Comment: @АндрейNOP привел, ранее не учитывал, что Grid я растянул на всю ширину кнопки самостоятельно. Однако необходимо, что бы ProgressBar был именно во всю кнопку

Comment: Все равно ничего не вылезает. PS: для того чтобы контент был растянут на всю длину/ширину, надо установить кнопке `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: А вообще вам надо покопаться в шаблоне кнопки и установить там для хрома кнопки `ClipToBounds`